# What is the temperate of a vacuum on earth?

Tags: temperature, vacuum

If a perfect vacuum was created within the earths atmosphere, what would it’s temperature be?

Answer (score -1):

If it was an absolutely perfect vacuum there would be no particles to have temperature, as the temperature is the average kinetic energy of the random motions of each particle.

Comment: The vacuum will be full of photons, and those photons have a temperature just like particles of matter.

Comment: I took a perfect vacuum to have no particles whatsoever, if the vacuum had any particles the temperature would be dependant on those and the question would need a lot more information.

Comment: 0.2K for all degrees of freedom would have zero point energy.